# Number Guessing Game Python

Tags: python, math

I want to write a number guessing game number taken from a user. Even though the right answer comes out the loop does not end. What should  I do?

```
    number=int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 100: "))
    guess=50
    n=1
    if number>100:
        number=int(input("Enter a number less than 100: "))
    if number<1:
        number=int(input("Enter a number greater than 1: "))
    while True:
        print("Your number is" +' '+ str(guess) +' '+ "?")
        ans=str(input("(g)reater,(l)ess or (b)ravo: "))
        for n in range(1,10):
            if ans=="g":
            guess=guess+guess//(2^n)
        elif ans=="l":
            guess=guess-guess//(2^n)
        elif ans=="b":
            print("Your number is " +' '+ str(guess) +' '+ "Well done for me")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move `break` from end into `if ans=="b":`

Comment: …also remove `print`s from both `if ans=="g":` and `if ans=="l":` blocks (no need to print the question twice) and replace `guess*0.5` with `guess//2` to avoid fractional numbers.